# `docker-compose.override.yml` `restart: no`: containers still start up after reboot

Tags: docker-compose

In my base configuration I have a few services with `restart: always` and in my override configuration I have those services with `restart: "no"`, but when I reboot the host the containers are started up again. I'm expecting the containers to still be stopped, am I missing something here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that since I created the containers before adding my override config the containers retained the `restart: always` policy.

I used this answer to update the policy to `no` and the containers do not restart now.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/37479753/4281998